# Get dummy (T/F) variables from list embedded within data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reduction

I have a data.frame in which cells contain a list of terms.

I wish to produce a new variable for each term found in that list indicating wether the term is present or not in that given cell.

I have multiple different such instance in a data.frame and do not know a priory the composition of the lists.

An example data.frame

```
require(plyr)

example<-data.frame(groups=letters)

example<-adply(example,
               1,
               function(x) data.frame(value=t(list(sample(LETTERS, 4)))))

    groups      value
1      a F, Y, N, X
2      b N, D, B, Y
3      c W, J, S, U
4      d I, S, N, A
5      e S, Z, Y, A
6      f O, R, J, A
```

From this, I wish to obtain

```
group     F     N     ...
1     A  TRUE  TRUE  ...
2     B FALSE  TRUE  ...
3     C FALSE FALSE  ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your request, here it is in function form

**Example**

```
myMatrix <- checkValues(example, makeMatrix=TRUE)
myMatrix

#        A     B     C     D     E     F  ...
#   a FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
#   b FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE ...
#   c FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
#   d FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE ...
#   e  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE ...
#   .
#   .
#   .
```

**Function**:

```
checkValues <- function(myDF, makeMatrix=FALSE, makeUnique=TRUE, sort=TRUE)  {
  # myDF should be a data frame containing columns `group` and `value`
  # if `makeMatrix` is T, will convert the list into a long matrix
  # `makeUnique`  and  `sort` only apply if `makeMatrix` is TRUE
  #   (otherwise, they are ignored)

  res<- 
  lapply(myDF$value, function(L1) 
      t(sapply(myDF$value, function(L2) L1 %in% L2 ))
  )

  # Make the names purtty 
  names(res) <- myDF$group

  for (i in 1:length(res))
      dimnames(res[[i]]) <- list(myDF$group, myDF$value[[i]])

  # convert the list to matrix
  if (makeMatrix)  {  
    res <- do.call(cbind, res)

    # remove duplicates, if required
    if (makeUnique) 
      res <- res[, !duplicated(res, MARGIN=2)]

    # order columns, if required
    if (sort)
      res <- res[, order(colnames(res))]
  }

  return(res)
}
```

Comment: Good one. I guess you should make that function(t) a function(g)

Comment: No, it's simply that your first answer had a small typo where `function(t) g %in% V` should in fact be `function(g) g %in% V`. I'm sorry about the confusion. Other confusion is that I'm not the question owner :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `data.table` and `reshape2` solution

```
library(data.table)
EX <- data.table(example)

data.table(dcast(EX[,list(value = unlist(value)),by=groups], groups~value))[,lapply(.SD, is.na),by = groups]
```

explaining the steps

- `EX[,list(value = unlist(value)),by=groups]` creates the data.table in long format (list values become a single colum
- `dcast(....)` converts to wide format with `columns`A`,...,`Z`but is an ugly mess of`NA` values
- `data.table()[,lapply(.SD), by =  groups]` goes through all the columns by group and coverts to a logical value. The `by` is not required (and will make it slightly slower), but then you would have to treat the groups column differently, and I couldn't be bothered.

---

## If you know the availabe elements beforehand

If you know what the  column names are beforehand, then this is a simple alternative to using `dcast`

Obviously you would replace `LETTERS` with the vector of possible values.

```
EX[, setNames(as.list(LETTERS%in% unlist(value)), LETTERS),by = groups]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the input here, I also created a require(plyr) solution.

Less elegant than both solutions, but for some reason, I still find it easer to read through plyr solutions.

Create a function that can produce a single dummy variable

```
single.value.to.dummy<-function(value.name, list.of.lists){
  ldply(.data=list.of.lists,
        function(list.element){ dummy<-value.name %in% list.element
                              names(dummy)<-value.name
                              return(dummy)
        })}
```

Apply this function to all unique values in the list of lists

```
list.of.lists.to.dummy<-function(list.of.lists){

#Extract unique values
  value.names<-unique(unlist(list.of.lists))

  dummy.frame<-llply(.data=value.names,
                      function(value.name){
                        dummy<-single.value.to.dummy(value.name, list.of.lists)
                        return(dummy)})

  return(data.frame(dummy.frame))
}

example<-cbind(example, list.of.lists.to.dummy(example$value))


groups      value     T     S     P     O     U     A     C     B     N     V     D     H     Y     F
1      a T, S, P, O  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
2      b U, A, C, B FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
3      c S, N, V, D FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
4      d H, Y, F, X FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
5      e M, Y, O, X FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
6      f Y, A, K, S FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```